# Read response from url

Tags: java, android, url

I have the url like this
[enter link description here](http://domscanner.ru/api/poll/login?phone=79232893050)

I want to read status and sms from response. How can I do it ?
I try to use this code, but it do not work perfect

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        URL url = null;
        int code;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                url = new URL("http://domscanner.ru/api/poll/login?phone=79232893050");
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .build();

                Call call = client.newCall(request);
                Response response = call.execute();
                code = response.code();
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    code = response.code();
                }
                String results;
                Log.i("TEST", "code " + code);
                if(code == 200) {
                    results = response.body().toString();
                } else {
                    results = "nothing";
                }

                Log.i("TEST ", "result " + results);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

in log 
code `200`

result

> okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@90b58f4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change if else statement like below:

```
if(code == 200) {
    results = response.body().string();
} else {
    results = "nothing";
}
```